# Laravel/DataTable fails at displaying ~80,000 rows

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, large-data-volumes

I'm trying to use DataTables with server side processing to display 80,000 rows (paginated), but Laravel crashes with the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in /Users/fin/Documents/dev/evway-new/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php on line 291`.

Here's my controller method where I'm fetching the rows:

```
public function data()
{
    $employees = Employee::get(); // ~80,000 employees

    return Datatables::of($employees)
        ->edit_column('created_at',function(Employee $employee) {
            return $employee->created_at->diffForHumans();
        })
        ->add_column('actions',function($employee){
            $actions = '<a href='. route('admin.employees.show', $employee->id) .'><i class="livicon" data-name="info" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="view employee"></i></a>
                        <a href='. route('admin.employees.edit', $employee->id) .'><i class="livicon" data-name="edit" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#428BCA" data-hc="#428BCA" title="update employee"></i></a>';

            $actions .= '<a href='. route('admin.employees.clone', $employee->id) .' data-target="#clone"><i class="livicon" data-name="plus" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#f56954" data-hc="#f56954" title="clone employee"></i></a>';

            $actions .= '<a href='. route('admin.employees.confirm-delete', $employee->id) .' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_confirm"><i class="livicon" data-name="remove" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#f56954" data-hc="#f56954" title="delete employee"></i></a>';
            return $actions;
        }
    )
    ->make(true);
}
```

and here is my JS where I'm configuring DataTable:

```
$(function() {
        var table = $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('admin.employees.data') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                { data: 'status', name: 'status' },
                { data: 'actions', name: 'actions', orderable: false, searchable: false }
            ]
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I fetching the Employees from the DB in the wrong way? is `get()` a bad idea?

Comment: why you have to display 80,000 rows ?

Comment: well they're pagintated, so it should only display 100 rows at a time, but there is a table of employees. the client has requested it.

Comment: I haven't really worked with Datatable plugin But your very first statement is the culprit. `$employees = Employee::get(); // ~80,000` employees .. This loads all 80k records into the memory. And then you pass this collection to `Datatables::of()` method. Instead of this I think you should be using  `Datatables::of(Employee::query())` , which I am assuming will handle the pagination and will load only the required number of employees

Comment: @Ankit this is the answer

Comment: should I post it as answer then if this solved your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't really worked with Datatable plugin But your very first statement is the culprit. `$employees = Employee::get(); // ~80,000 employees` .. This loads all 80k records into the memory. And then you pass this collection to `Datatables::of()` method. Instead of this I think you should be using `Datatables::of(Employee::query())` , which I am assuming will handle the pagination and will load only the required number of employees –

Comment: Nice answer. In addition to above if you are using relation to retrieve model data then get rid of get() at the end. Eg: Datatables::of($user->contacts()->where()) without the get at the end

Comment: It is not working, giving error

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase your  php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 360      ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (I CHANGED THIS VALUE)
max_input_time = 120          ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 128M
```